# How can I change the number of threads Rayon uses?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, rust-cargo, rayon

I'm using the Rayon library:

```
extern crate rayon;

const N: usize = 1_000_000_000;
const W: f64 = 1f64/(N as f64);

fn f(x: f64) -> f64 {
    4.0/(1.0+x*x)
}

fn main() { 
    use rayon::prelude::*;
    let sum : f64 = (0..N)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| f(W*((i as f64)+0.5)))
        .sum::<f64>();
    println!("pi = {}", W*sum);
}
```

I want to run this code using different number of threads: 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I have read the documentation about [How many threads will Rayon spawn?](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-many-threads-will-rayon-spawn) which says:

> By default, Rayon uses the same number of threads as the number of CPUs available. Note that on systems with hyperthreading enabled this equals the number of logical cores and not the physical ones.
>
> If you want to alter the number of threads spawned, you can set the environmental variable `RAYON_NUM_THREADS` to the desired number of threads or use the [`ThreadPoolBuilder::build_global` function](https://docs.rs/rayon/*/rayon/struct.ThreadPoolBuilder.html#method.build_global) method.

However, the steps are not clear for me. How can I do this on my Windows 10 PC?

Comment: well you could do what it's written... https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.1/rayon/struct.ThreadPoolBuilder.html

Comment: ohh.. got it. just need to include this `rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(22).build_global().unwrap();` . Thank you

Answer (score 22):

Just include in fn main(). The num_threads accepts the number of threads.

`rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(4).build_global().unwrap();`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to set a global, you can create a function called 'create_pool'. This helper function constructs a Rayon ThreadPool object from num_threads.

```
pub fn create_pool(num_threads: usize) -> Result<rayon::ThreadPool, YOURERRORENUM> {
   match rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
      .num_threads(num_threads)
      .build()
   {
      Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
      Ok(pool) => Ok(pool),
   }
}
```

Then call your code from inside this create_pool. This will limit all Rayon functions to the num_threads you set.

```
[...]
    create_pool(num_threads)?.install(|| {
       YOURCODE
     })?;
[...]
```

For more see https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-for-writing-python-extensions-in-rust-d35ea3a4ec29